# how to match rgb image pixels with corresponding pointcloud points

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, point-cloud-library, luxonis

I have a color image, corresponding point cloud captured by oak-D camera(see the image below) and i want to get the information of pixels in the color image and corresponding point cloud value in point cloud.
how can i get this information?  for instance, i have a pixel value (200,250) in the color image and how to know the corresponding point value in the point cloud?
any help would be appreciated.[image]

Comment: Not sure where you are stuck. Can you find the bottle? How are you trying to find the bottle? If you can find the bottle, are you able to map the pixels into the point cloud data?

Comment: If you want better assistance, you should provide the actual, individual images, rather than montages of reduced size images.

Comment: Hi Mark! i am not trying to find the bottle. i want to map the pixels in the color into the point cloud data.

Comment: I do not know how to map pixels in the image into point cloud data. do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to project a 2D image to a 3D point cloud using the computed disparity map. To do this you will also need to know about your camera intrinsics. Since you are using the oak-D, you should be able to get everything you need with the following piece of code.

```py
with dai.Device(pipeline) as device:
    calibData = device.readCalibration()
    
    # get right intrinsic matrix
    w, h = monoRight.getResolutionSize()
    K_right = calibData.getCameraIntrinsics(dai.CameraBoardSocket.RIGHT, dai.Size2f(w, h))

    # get left intrinsic matrix
    w, h = monoLeft.getResolutionSize()
    K_left = calibData.getCameraIntrinsics(dai.CameraBoardSocket.LEFT, dai.Size2f(w, h))
    
    R_left = calibData.getStereoLeftRectificationRotation()
    R_right = calibData.getStereoRightRectificationRotation()
    x_baseline = calibData.getBaselineDistance()
```

Once you have all you camera parameters, you should be able to use opencv to approach this.

First you will need to construct the Q matrix (or rectified transformation matrix).
[image: Q matrix]

You will need to provide

- The left and right intrinsic calibration matrices
- The Translation vector from the coordinate system of the first camera to the second camera
- The Rotation matrix from the coordinate system of the first camera to the second camera

Here's a coded example:

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2

Q = np.zeros((4,4))
cv2.stereoRectify(cameraMatrix1=K_left,  # left intrinsic matrix
                  cameraMatrix2=K_right, # right intrinsic matrix
                  distCoeffs1=0,  
                  distCoeffs2=0,  
                  imageSize=imageSize, # pass in the image size 
                  R=R_left,            # Rotation matrix from camera 1 to camera 2
                  T=x_baseline,        # Translation matrix from camera 1 to camera 2          
                  R1=None, 
                  R2=None, 
                  P1= None, 
                  P2= None, 
                  Q=Q);
```

Next you will need to reproject the image to 3D, using the known disparity map and the Q matrix. The operation is illustrated below, but opencv makes this much easier.

[image: Operation to reproject to 3D]

```py
xyz = cv2.reprojectImageTo3D(disparity, Q)
```

This will give you an array of 3D points. This array specifically has the shape: (rows, columns, 3), where the 3 corresponds the (x,y,z) coordinate of the point cloud. Now you can use the a pixel location to index into xyz and find it's corresponding (x, y, z) point.

```py
pix_row = 200
pix_col = 250
point_cloud_coordinate = xyz[pix_row, pix_col, :]
```

See the docs for more details

- [cv2.stereoRectify()](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga617b1685d4059c6040827800e72ad2b6)
- [cv2.reprojectImageTo3D()](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga1bc1152bd57d63bc524204f21fde6e02)